# CakePHP find conditions generate SQL "WHERE ... AND 1"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

Here's my code:

```
    $attendances = $this->Pupil->Attendance->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'Pupil.group_id'=>$group,
                'Attendance.date' >= $start,
                'Attendance.date' <= $end
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Here's the SQL that gets generated:

```
SELECT [many different fields from a few tables] WHERE `Pupil`.`group_id` = 7 AND 1
```

The value of $start is 2011-06-06 and end is 2011-06-10 (verified by using debug() in the view).

Why is Cake generating the condition "AND 1", and omitting my conditions?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm extremely slow today and I apologise for insulting everyone's intelligence.

The problem, of course, is that >= and <= are not inside the quotes.

The correct code, for anyone who has a similarly braindead moment, is

```
    $attendances = $this->Pupil->Attendance->find('all',
        array(
            'conditions'=>array(
                'Pupil.group_id'=>$group,
                'AND'=>array(
                    'Attendance.date >=' => $start,
                    'Attendance.date <=' => $end
                )
            )
        )
    );
```